# Is there a way to access the @Component declared service properties in the bundle's class code?

Tags: java, osgi

I have an osgi service component with properties set on the @Component decorator (specifically event topics).  Is there a way to access the event topic values in the code?  And even better, is there a way to dynamically control what event topics i need this service bundle to be registered for as a listener?

```
@Component( immediate=true, service = {EventHandler.class}, 
property = {"event.topics=PRICES/STOCKS/NASDAQ/SH"})
public class OrderEntry implements EventHandler{

@Activate
protected void activate(){
    // TODO:
    //    access event.topics property values
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `ComponentContext` in your `activate()` method. The `ComponentContext` provides access to the properties with the `getProperties()` method. This is unfortunately a Dictionary ...

```
@Component( immediate=true, service = {EventHandler.class}, 
  property = {"event.topics=PRICES/STOCKS/NASDAQ/SH"})
public class OrderEntry implements EventHandler{

  @Activate protected void activate(ComponentContext context){
      System.out.println("Props " + context.getProperties());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Map` passed to your activate method to receive the component properties.

```java
@Component(immediate=true, property = {"event.topics=PRICES/STOCKS/NASDAQ/SH"})
public class OrderEntry implements EventHandler {
  @Activate
  void activate(Map<String,Object> properties){
    Object eventTopics = properties.get("event.topics");
  }
}
```